# C++ Have two child classes share a variable from their base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

So say I have 3 classes: Base, A, and B.

Base is a base class for both class A and class B.

Base has a variable val that A and B can access.

How would I get it to work where I can set the val variable through class A, and it is reflected in class B?

For example:

I know this code below won't work because I am creating an OBJECT of the type a and b.

What I want to do is to simply have a and b share the same variable so that whenever `a` does something to it, it is reflected in `b`.

```
a aa;
b bb;

aa.SetVal(50000);
cout << aa.GetVal() << endl;
cout << bb.GetVal() << endl;
```

In the end I'd want both `cout` lines to print out 50000.

**EDIT: The classes A and B will be doing different operations and just need to be able to access/change the val variable in base**

Comment: You have to understand that the memory locations of the members allocated for the base class sub-objects of `aa` and `bb` are in distinct memory locations. Sharing means accessing the same memory location from different places, which is something you cannot achieve with standard inheritence unless you choose to manipulate a static base class member - you can see several examples for the latter in the answers now. The question is, is thats the right design and if the value you're manipulating actually is supposed to be an "instance-less" value.

Comment: I just posted an edit of what I mean to do. I would need class a & b to access the same variable and change it.

Comment: When you say, "classes A & B will be doing different operations", does that imply `A` and `B` are actually unrelated types? That only because of necessity have similar interfaces?

Comment: Yes, they are unrelated types. The only necessary thing they need to have in common is access to the same variable.

Comment: See, unrelated types should *not* be inheriting from a common `Base` class. Inheritance models an "is-a" relationship - which implies that `A` and `B` will be types which share common properties because they are similar. Obviously they're not equal, but they both are a `Base`. Inheriting just for sharing a static class member is bad design - actually I'd rather use a well hidden global over such a design.

Comment: Ok let me try to explain it again, I got it wrong the first time. They ARE related types. They will each be a subset of base. While they will be doing totally different operations, all they need is access to a shared value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42435/discussion-between-sempus-and-thokra)

Answer (score 3):

You could make the member a static member of the base class, then all derived classes could access it, however any object of a derived that changes the static member would change it for every other object.

```
class Base
{
public:

    int GetVal()
    {
        return val;
    }

    void SetVal( int newVal )
    {
        val = newVal;
    }
private:

    static int val;
};

// Need to instantiate the static variable somewhere
int Base::val = 0;

class A : public Base
{};

class B : public Base
{};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a job for *references*, not for classes. Just have one class `X` and create a reference to the object:

```
X  aa;
X& bb = aa;
aa.SetVal(50000);
std::cout << aa.GetVal() << std::endl;
std::cout << bb.GetVal() << std::endl;
```

The output will be:

> 50000
>   50000

Remember to always use the right tool for the job and keep things simple.

---

> The main goal is that those two classes will be doing different things but will need to be able to access and share a single variable.

An idea to solve this is to extract the common variable in another class, namely `S`, which will be passed to `A` and `B` like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<S> s = new S();
A aa(s);
B bb(s)
```

Now, both `aa` and `bb` share the same `S` object and can modify it very easily. Notice that the constructor of both `A` and `B` should store the `std::shared_ptr<S>` as well:

```
class A { // and B
private:
    std::shared_ptr<S> s;
public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<S> as) : s(as) {}
};
```

The variable `s` will last as long as any of `aa` and `bb` is *alive*: when both `aa` and `bb` gets deallocated or go out of scope, the variable `s` will be deallocated as well.

If the type of the common variable should be on the stack, you can also just use references, but watch out for the lifetime of `aa`, `bb` and that variable:

```
int s = 0;
A aa(s);
B bb(s);
```

with:

```
class A { // and B
private:
    int& s; // or any other type
public:
    A(int& as) : s(as) {}
};
```

But as a general rule of thumb I'd avoid shared state between objects. Most of the time, depending on the context, you can refactor your code and get rid of the shared dependency.

Comment: What if I am going to need to have each class(A&B) do different things?

Comment: @Sempus, if two completely different classes share the same state you are doing something wrong. Read about *encapsulation* and keep your classes as clean and as independent from each other as you can.

Comment: The main goal is that those two classes will be doing different things but will need to be able to access and share a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Base {
    static int value;
public:
    virtual ~Base() { }

    void setVal(const int& val) {
        value = val;
    }

    int getVal() const {
        return value;
    }
};

int Base::value = 0;

class A : public Base {
};

class B : public Base {
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.setVal(20);
    std::cout << b.getVal(); // 20
}
```

Comment: Great! I got this to work. Now I just have to move them to different files and get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the shared value is static in the base class, then all instances of derived classes will see exactly that one base class member.

If the value is not static, then each instance of a class will have its own copy whether or not the value is in a base class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Do you want all instances of A and B to share the same value? if so, declare it as static in the base class.
if not, how do you want to choose which one will share the value?